# Is it possible to run my local activedirectory powershell module against a remote dc?

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have completed all the prerequisites for getting remote connection etc. Everything is in place. I am logging in from windows 7 with rsat installed. The server is 2008 NOT R2. I can remote in successfully over https, but how do i get my local activedirectorymodule to be run against the remote server?

Comment: Have you tried the `-server` parameter that most of the AD module cmdlets appear to support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell ActiveDirectory module depends on Active Directory Web Services ([ADWS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391908%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)). It's ships with Windows 2008 R2 (and latter) but can also be installed on older DCs. The name of the package is Active Directory Management Gateway ([ADMG](http://blogs.technet.com/b/activedirectoryua/archive/2009/09/17/what-is-the-active-directory-management-gateway-service.aspx)).

In my experience: if you want to use AD module against selected DC/domain, the best option is to create PSDrive that will point to this server/ domain:

```
New-PSDrive -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Name MyAD -Root '' -Server YourDC
```

Once you cd into this drive, any command you will run will target selected DC.